# After importing object from illustrator it auto animates making it impossible to animate on my own

Tags: after-effects, animation

I import the file using right click and import.
Untitled1 is at position A at 0:00
Untitled1 is at position B at 0:01
Untitled1 is invisible on Composition at 0:02

Can't add keyframes to Untitled1 layer.
Why is this behavior so?
I'd like to animate Untitled1 normally.

Comment: You need to tell us what exactly you did (esp. how you've imported the file) and should provide a screenshot where we can see the problem. Also, I don't know what you mean with "auto animates". You can click "edit" below your text to add these details.

Comment: I saw you edited the question, but I'm still lost. Could you share the AI file and your After Effects project file?

Comment: Maybe it'¿s a computer glitch, I ended up abandoning the project altogether. will rellook at some given time in the future thank you musch.